# Как с помощью addPixmap сделать изменяемую иконку при наведении указателя мыши?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qss, qpushbutton

В коде программы имеются кнопки, которые описываются через:

```
 `icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)`
```

В интернете нашел вариации `Normal`, `Active`, `Disabled`, `Selected`, так же есть **`on`** и **`off`**.

Как с помощью `addPixmap` сделать изменяемую иконку при наведении указателя мыши?

Я использую: *Windows 10*, *Python 3.7*, *PyQt5*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте **таблицы стилей** Qt.
Терминология и синтаксические правила таблицы стилей Qt практически идентичны HTML CSS.

```
import sys
from PyQt5     import QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pb1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pb1.setFixedSize(200, 200)

# + vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
QSS = """
QPushButton {
    background: #fff;
    border-image: url(LightOff.png);
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background: #33f;
    border-image: url(LightOn.png);
}
"""
# + ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)                              # <---

    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> а есть ли возможность сделать чтобы при наведении на иконку выскакивало небольшое окошко с подписью, определенного размера и строго сбоку от иконки. ? 
>   только не стандартный Tooltip...

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pb1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pb1.setFixedSize(200, 200)
        self.pb1.installEventFilter(self)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)                             
        self.pb1.setMouseTracking(True)                         

        self.customToolTip = QLabel()                           
        self.customToolTip.setObjectName("customtooltip")       

    def eventFilter(self,object,event):            
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverLeave:                 
            self.customToolTip.hide()
            return True          
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverEnter:
            pos = self.pos()
            self.update_tooltip(pos)
            return True
        return False

    def update_tooltip(self, pos):                                     
        self.customToolTip.setText("  В размер иконки, \nопределенной длины и \nстрого сбоку от иконки  ")
        self.customToolTip.move(pos + QtCore.QPoint(250, 0))
        self.customToolTip.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.customToolTip.adjustSize()
        self.customToolTip.show()         


# + 
QSS = """
QPushButton {
    background: #fff;
    border-image: url(LightOff.png);
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background: #33f;
    border-image: url(LightOn.png);
}
#customtooltip {                         /*  <---  */
    background: red; 
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)                              
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а есть ли возможность сделать чтобы при наведении на иконку выскакивало небольшое окошко с подписью? только не стандартный Tooltip...

Comment: @biomotor объясните пожалуйста чем `небольшое окошко с подписью` должно отличаться от `Tooltip` ?

Comment: В размер иконки, определенной длины и строго сбоку от иконки.

Comment: @biomotor я добавил то, что вы спрашивали.

Comment: Подскажите, а как сделать чтобы кнопка меняла цвет фона, по центру была иконка (то же самое что в примере) и при этом иконка была меньшего размера и по центру кнопки? к примеру меняя размер кнопки 30,40,50 пикселей размер иконки оставался 30 пикселей.

Comment: @biomotor задавать вопросы в комментариях - это плохая практика. Если у вас что-то не получается, сформируйте новый вопрос, прикрепите минимальный пример и напишите что вы пробовали и что не так.

Comment: а можно то же самое но для двух и более кнопок, и для каждой свой tooltip? чет поковырялся, ничего не вышло... (

Comment: @biomotor Думаю, что все возможно. Задайте новый вопрос, приведите пример своего кода, напишете что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.